# Web filtering, dhcp, proxies in a distro?

Tags: server, proxy, dhcp

I want to ditch our Dave's web filtering because it blocks anything our dear Gov do not like, but I also want to protect my children from porn. I am thinking I can install a cut down Ubuntu distro on my server (running Win7 Pro 32bit) using a VM or something. I have a virgin superhub so I will need to shut down the build in DHCP server as I have no way to configure that so I think what I need is a DHCP server and filtering software. Does this sound correct, and is it easy to set up using Ubuntu? I must be able to update the filtering in case of false positives or negatives.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenDNS has a DNS-based filtering solution that can block a whole bunch of different categories of websites, and gives you the ability to override the actions for certain websites.  Here's a setup that might work for you:

- Get a [free OpenDNS Home account](http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/).
- Install Ubuntu, and then [set it up as your network router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router).
- Install `dnsmasq` for serving DNS and DHCP to your LAN.
- Install `ddclient` if you do not have a static public IP.
- After OpenDNS account setup, go through their tutorials on how to configure `ddclient` to update the IP address associated with your account and edit your resolv.conf file with their DNS server addresses.